# How to add an xml element and wrap the data (inner-text) in CDATA tags using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, elementtree, cdata

I'm struggling to find a good example of how one would add an XML Element to an XML Document and also add the data (inner-text) to this same element, but wrap the data in CDATA tags?

Here is an example of what I need.  I have the following document.

```
<data>
     <config>
          <documentation>This is my documentation<documentation>
     </config>
</data>
```

I then want to add a  element and CDATA as the inner-text.  So it would look something like this.  The data that I need to wrap in CDATA tags can be fairly large and will need to be read/referenced from file.

```
<data>
     <config>
              <documentation>This is my documentation<documentation>
              <script><![CDATA[
              function foo()
              …
              End
              ]]>
              </script>
     </config>
</data>
```

I then need to write the changes out to a new document... (so that I have the original and the additions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174890/how-to-output-cdata-using-elementtree and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474754/how-to-keep-comments-while-parsing-xml-using-python-elementtree?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the .CDATA() method provided by lxml.

http://lxml.de/api.html#cdata

Just create a SubElement as normal

```
some_var = root.find('config')
another_var = etree.SubElement(some_var, 'script')
another_var.text = etree.CDATA(another_var.text)
```

Then you can write the data out as normal.