# Faithfully Preserve Comments in Parsed XML

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, elementtree

I'd like to preserve comments as faithfully as possible while manipulating XML.

I managed to preserve comments, but the contents are getting XML-escaped.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# add_host_to_tomcat.py

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from CommentedTreeBuilder import CommentedTreeBuilder
parser = CommentedTreeBuilder()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = "/opt/lucee/tomcat/conf/server.xml"

    # this is the important part: use the comment-preserving parser
    tree = ET.parse(filename, parser)

    # get the node to add a child to
    engine_node = tree.find("./Service/Engine")

    # add a node: Engine.Host
    host_node = ET.SubElement(
        engine_node,
        "Host",
        name="local.mysite.com",
        appBase="webapps"
    )
    # add a child to new node: Engine.Host.Context
    ET.SubElement(
        host_node,
        'Context',
        path="",
        docBase="/path/to/doc/base"
    )

    tree.write('out.xml')
```

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# CommentedTreeBuilder.py

from xml.etree import ElementTree

class CommentedTreeBuilder ( ElementTree.XMLTreeBuilder ):
    def __init__ ( self, html = 0, target = None ):
        ElementTree.XMLTreeBuilder.__init__( self, html, target )
        self._parser.CommentHandler = self.handle_comment

    def handle_comment ( self, data ):
        self._target.start( ElementTree.Comment, {} )
        self._target.data( data )
        self._target.end( ElementTree.Comment )
```

However, comments like like:

```xml
  <!--
EXAMPLE HOST ENTRY:
    <Host name="lucee.org" appBase="webapps">
         <Context path="" docBase="/var/sites/getrailo.org" />
     <Alias>www.lucee.org</Alias>
     <Alias>my.lucee.org</Alias>
    </Host>

HOST ENTRY TEMPLATE:
    <Host name="[ENTER DOMAIN NAME]" appBase="webapps">
         <Context path="" docBase="[ENTER SYSTEM PATH]" />
     <Alias>[ENTER DOMAIN ALIAS]</Alias>
    </Host>
  -->
```

End up as:

```xml
  <!--
            EXAMPLE HOST ENTRY:
    &lt;Host name="lucee.org" appBase="webapps"&gt;
         &lt;Context path="" docBase="/var/sites/getrailo.org" /&gt;
         &lt;Alias&gt;www.lucee.org&lt;/Alias&gt;
         &lt;Alias&gt;my.lucee.org&lt;/Alias&gt;
    &lt;/Host&gt;

    HOST ENTRY TEMPLATE:
    &lt;Host name="[ENTER DOMAIN NAME]" appBase="webapps"&gt;
         &lt;Context path="" docBase="[ENTER SYSTEM PATH]" /&gt;
         &lt;Alias&gt;[ENTER DOMAIN ALIAS]&lt;/Alias&gt;
    &lt;/Host&gt;
   -->
```

I also tried `self._target.data( saxutils.unescape(data) )` in `CommentedTreeBuilder.py`, but it didn't seem to do anything. In fact, I think the problem happens somewhere after the `handle_commment()` step.

By the way, this question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474754/how-to-keep-comments-while-parsing-xml-using-python-elementtree).

Comment: This is a lot easier in Python 3.8. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59561426/407651.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Tested with Python 2.7 and 3.5, the following code should work as intended.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# CommentedTreeBuilder.py
from xml.etree import ElementTree

class CommentedTreeBuilder(ElementTree.TreeBuilder):
    def comment(self, data):
        self.start(ElementTree.Comment, {})
        self.data(data)
        self.end(ElementTree.Comment)
```

Then, in the main code use

```
parser = ElementTree.XMLParser(target=CommentedTreeBuilder())
```

as the parser instead of the current one.

By the way, comments work correctly out of the box with `lxml`. That is, you can just do

```
import lxml.etree as ET
tree = ET.parse(filename)
```

without needing any of the above.

Comment: Both solutions seem to preserve the comments, thanks! But other elements get re-formatted (and attributes reordered, potentially). I know it doesn't matter for machine-readability, but for my purposes (human readability, version control, and only touching explicitly-touched elements), it matters. FWIW, my original version happens to leave other elements intact (i.e. formatted as the original had been).  This answer does address my explicit question, so it will get the answer award, but I'd like to know if non-comment-element formatting preservation is also possible.

Comment: As far as I can see, the only things that gets modified are the ordering of attributes and the whitespace inside tags (correct me if I'm missing anything). You normally should not have or care about the latter. Since attributes are stored in a dictionary in `xml`, their ordering is random in the output. To fix that, you can use a workaround similar to the comments' one, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2741480/2997179. Or as quick testing with `lxml` showed, it seems to preserve the attribute order and seems like a viable solution. Either way, I think this deserves a separate SO question.

Comment: Okay.. on top of attributes, `xml` also discards processing instruction tags (e.g. `<?xml-stylesheet href="mystyle.css" type="text/css"?>`) and renames xmlns namespaces. Again, `lxml` does neither.

Comment: Both `xml` and `lxml` also omit `<?xml...?>` and `<!DOCTYPE ...>` declarations by default. http://stackoverflow.com/q/18173983/2997179 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/12966488/2997179 have solutions for this.

Comment: Works with Python 3.5.4.

Answer (score 19):

[Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.TreeBuilder) added the `insert_comments` argument to `TreeBuilder` which:

> `class xml.etree.ElementTree.TreeBuilder(element_factory=None, *, comment_factory=None, pi_factory=None, insert_comments=False, insert_pis=False)`
>
> When insert_comments and/or insert_pis is true, comments/pis will be inserted into the tree if they appear within the root element (but not outside of it).

Example:

```
parser = ElementTree.XMLParser(target=ElementTree.TreeBuilder(insert_comments=True))
```

Comment: Worked for me with Python3.8

Comment: what about the case for outside of root element? Is there any way to preserve the comments?

Answer (score 5):

Martin's Code didn't work for me. I modified the same with the following which works as intended.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

class CommentedTreeBuilder(ET.XMLTreeBuilder):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CommentedTreeBuilder, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._parser.CommentHandler = self.comment

    def comment(self, data):
        self._target.start(ET.Comment, {})
        self._target.data(data)
        self._target.end(ET.Comment)
```

This is the test

```
    parser=CommentedTreeBuilder()
    tree = ET.parse(filename, parser)
    tree.write('out.xml')
```

Comment: This is python 3.52 and above

Answer (score 5):

Martin's answer is correct, only it's missing some code,
I understand that it may be obvious to more experienced programers, but as a new programer it took a minute for me to understand:
Marting's answer:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree import ElementTree

class CommentedTreeBuilder(ElementTree.TreeBuilder):
# This class will retain remarks and comments opposed to the xml parser default
    def comment(self, data):
        self.start(ElementTree.Comment, {})
        self.data(data)
        self.end(ElementTree.Comment)

# the missing part:
def parse_xml_with_remarks(filepath):
    ctb = CommentedTreeBuilder()
    xp = ET.XMLParser(target=ctb)
    tree = ET.parse(filepath, parser=xp)
    return tree

# parsing the file, and getting root
tree=parse_xml_with_remarks(file)
root=tree.getroot()
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like both answers from @Martin and @sukhbinder didn't work for me... So made this as a workable completed solution on python 3.x

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

string = '''<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <!--Test
    -->
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
</data>'''

class CommentedTreeBuilder(ElementTree.TreeBuilder):
    def comment(self, data):
        self.start(ElementTree.Comment, {})
        self.data(data)
        self.end(ElementTree.Comment)

parser = ElementTree.XMLParser(target=CommentedTreeBuilder())
tree = ElementTree.fromstring(string, parser)
print(tree.find("./*[0]").text)
# or ElementTree.parse(filename, parser)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me out of the box (python 3.9):

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import XMLParser, TreeBuilder, parse

ctb = TreeBuilder(insert_comments=True) # This does the trick :)
xp = XMLParser(target=ctb)
mytree = parse('sample.xml', parser=xp)
root = mytree.getroot()
mytree.write('sample_modified.xml')
```