# How can I preserve the comments while appending into an xml file in python?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree

When I am trying to write into an xml file using elementree,the comments are getting deleted and also there are unnecessary blank lines included. How Can I preserve the comments ?

Comment: You're new around here, aren't you? Please read about MCVE https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve then edit your MCVE code into your question.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/33573807/407651