# How do I grab the data in the following xml file and format the long number using python?

Tags: xml, python-3.x

So I have the following XML file and I was wondering what the commands are to grab each comment with the date and time as well as each v row associated with that date and time. I'm assuming I use a triple for loop and insert the commands into it however I'm not exactly sure what those commands are. I want to use `from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET` and I'm thinking I start the code like this

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

# find the first 'item' object
for elem in root:
    for subelement in elem:
        for row in subelement:
            for v in row:
                print (v.attrib)
```

But I don't know how to grab the comment and I'm not sure the nested for loops will get me to the right area and if the command is right. So what would the right commands be to accomplish this goal?

```
-<rrd>
    -<rra>
        -<database>
            <!-- 2019-05-19 13:15:15 CDT / 1558289715 -->
            -<row>
                <v>3.4000000000e+01</v>
            </row>

            <!-- 2019-05-19 13:15:30 CDT / 1558289730 -->
            -<row>
                <v>3.4000000000e+01</v>
            </row>

            <!-- 2019-05-19 13:15:45 CDT / 1558289745 -->
            -<row>
                <v>3.4000000000e+01</v>
            </row>
        -</database>
    -</rra>
-</rrd>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an xpath expression to select every comment that is followed by a row element and the contents of row/v:

```
from lxml import etree

with open('file.xml') as f:
    doc = etree.parse(f)
it = iter(doc.xpath(
    '//comment()[following-sibling::row] | //row/v/text()'
))
for db_date, db_value in zip(it, it):
    print(f'date: {db_date.text.strip()}  value: {db_value}')

date: 2019-05-19 13:15:15 CDT / 1558289715  value: 3.4000000000e+01
date: 2019-05-19 13:15:30 CDT / 1558289730  value: 3.4000000000e+01
date: 2019-05-19 13:15:45 CDT / 1558289745  value: 3.4000000000e+01
```

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, ElementTree's parser doesn't preserve comments, so your options are to either [implement your own comment parser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34324359/4739755), or use the `lxml` library (can be installed with `pip`).

Once you've done that, you can access the comment nodes as children of the `<database>` element (siblings to `<row>`) just like any other:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

for rra in rrd:
    for database in rra:
        for node in database:
            print(node.text.strip())

2019-05-19 13:15:15 CDT / 1558289715

2019-05-19 13:15:30 CDT / 1558289730

2019-05-19 13:15:45 CDT / 1558289745
```

Side note: `lxml` makes this easier if you *only* want comment nodes because you can check the node type (base ElementTree just shows them all as `Element`):

```py
import lxml
import lxml.etree as ET

for rra in rrd:
    for database in rra:
        for node in database:
            if isinstance(node, lxml.etree._Comment):
                print(node.text.strip())

2019-05-19 13:15:15 CDT / 1558289715
2019-05-19 13:15:30 CDT / 1558289730
2019-05-19 13:15:45 CDT / 1558289745
```

Comment: So the code at the top one grabs the row i.e. 3.4000000000e+01 and the bottom piece of code grabs the comment right?

Comment: They're both doing the same thing (grabbing the comment text), just with different libraries. `xml.etree.ElementTree` is the first section, `lxml` is the second. In the first one, only the comment nodes have any text, so they're the only ones printed.