# How to read commented text from XML file in python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am able to read the xml file in a using 'import xml.etree.ElementTree as et'. But my problem is to read the **commented text** given in the data file, how to read this:
For example in the below xml, I want to read **BaseVehicle** is **1997 Cadillac Catera**

```
<App action="A" id="1">
    <BaseVehicle id="8559"/>
    <!--  1997 Cadillac Catera  -->
    <Qty>1</Qty>
    <PartType id="4472"/>
    <!--  Electrical/Headlight/Switch  -->
    <Part>SW1406</Part>
</App>
```

Comment: check this : https://bugs.python.org/issue8277

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I am getting error - "ImportError: cannot import name 'XMLTreeBuilder' from 'xml.etree.ElementTree" 
Also When I searched and tried to use the below code:

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard behaviour of ElementTree is to ignore comments. However, comments can be preserved by using a custom parser object. This has become easier in [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#xml), where the `xml.etree.ElementTree.TreeBuilder` target can be configured to process comment events in order to include them in the generated tree.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

parser = ET.XMLParser(target=ET.TreeBuilder(insert_comments=True)) # Python 3.8
tree = ET.parse("app.xml", parser)

# Get the comment nodes
for node in tree.iter():
    if "function Comment" in str(node.tag): 
        print(node.text)
```

Output:

> 1997 Cadillac Catera
> Electrical/Headlight/Switch

With older versions of Python, some more code is needed. See [Faithfully Preserve Comments in Parsed XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33573807/407651).