# python 2.7: accessing comment in XML

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, elementtree

I been using ElementTree to read XML file, and were able to parse XML properly. But I don't know how to read comment, especially where child context is important. In this specific case, I like to read comment for NY, that air, bus and trail is avilable and store it in a dictionary (name:comment).

```
<spirit: st>
     .....   
     <spirit:fa>
            <spirit:name>NY</spirit:name>
            <spirit:den>3</spirit:bitWidth>
            <spirit:metro>true</spirit:metro>
            <!-- air, bus, train all available -->
            <spirit:access>air</spirit:access>
         </spirit:fa>
      .....
```

My code:

```
for state in data.findall('spirit:st', IPXACT_MAP):
    for city in state.findall('spirit:fa', IPXACT_MAP):
        access = city.find('spirit:access', IPXACT_MAP) 
        #read comment and set city_access_d[city.text] = comment
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/33573807/407651. In Python 3.8, it is easier to read and preserve comments: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59561426/407651

Comment: Went through them, but they are more related to preserving comment. I just don't know how to read comment and store them in a variable. I have a rudimentary knowledge on elementtree.

Comment: I haven't done it with Python 2.7, but in a tree where the comment nodes are preserved, surely there must be a way to identify these nodes and get their text content (just as in the linked answer for Python 3.8).

Comment: "especially where child context is important." What does that mean?

Comment: Are you able to use lxml? With lxml you should be able to use XPath to select the correct comment. Let me know if you want me to add an example.

Comment: Also, `city.text` doesn't make much sense because `city` is the `spirit:fa` element and the only text nodes (.text and .tail of its children) are whitespace.

Comment: Hi @DanielHaley, I haven't use lxml, would appreciate if you can provide an example. Also, you are correct. key should be name.txt or something.

Comment: @mzjn what I mean is that every city has it's own comment, and I need to capture comments per city.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use [lxml](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html), you should be able to select the comment() with XPath.

Here's an example. I've removed the namespace prefixes to simplify it.

```
from lxml import etree

xml = """
<st>
    <fa>
        <name>NY</name>
        <den>3</den>
        <!-- ignore me -->
        <metro>true</metro>
        <!-- air, bus, train all available -->
        <access>air</access>
    </fa>
</st>
"""

parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
tree = etree.fromstring(xml, parser=parser)

city_access_d = {}
for city in tree.xpath(".//fa"):
    name = city.xpath("name")[0].text
    comment = city.xpath("comment()[following-sibling::node()[1][self::access]]")[0]
    city_access_d[name] = comment.text.strip()

print city_access_d
```

printed output...

```
{'NY': 'air, bus, train all available'}
```

You could also use the following XPath if for some reason you didn't want to create the XMLParser...

```
comment = city.xpath("comment()[following-sibling::node()[not(self::text())][1][self::access]]")[0]
```