# Why comments are missing after writing to same xml using element tree in python?

Tags: python, python-2.x, elementtree

Lets say I have TARGET_FILE.xml like below

After updating value of Member and writing it to same file using

TARGET_FILE_TREE.write(TARGET_FILE)

The overwritten file has no commented line as in original file, could you please help in tacking this issue

This is my main code:

```
for node in NvItemData_Nodes: 
    if node.attrib.get("id") == "5153": 
        print "yes" 
        print node.find('Member').text 
        node.find('Member').text = SVN 
        print node.find('Member').text 
TARGET_FILE_TREE.write(TARGET_FILE)
```

Comment: for node in NvItemData_Nodes:
        if node.attrib.get("id") == "5153":
            print "yes"
            print node.find('Member').text
            node.find('Member').text = SVN
            print node.find('Member').text

    TARGET_FILE_TREE.write(TARGET_FILE)

Is my main code

Answer (score 1):

When reading the xml-file, the data is converted to a python-data strucute. Because the comments are just comments they are discarded and not saved in this data structure. (That is what comments are for.)

When saving, the python-data-structure you edited is converted back to an xml format and the previous data is overwritten. As the comment is not part of the data structure, it is not written to the fil again.

In Python 3.8 you can preserve comments like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59561426/8106583

For Python 2.7 I found this solution to preserve comments: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34324359/8106583

Comment: @SHASHIBHUSHAN GOTUR Please accept the answer if it worked for you.