# Get commented nodes in XML

Tags: python, xml

Env: Python 3.9.7, Windows 10

How can I get XPATHs of the commented nodes?

---

**Example XML (ex.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank updated="yes">2</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E">AUS</neighbor>
        <!-- A1 -->
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W">SWI</neighbor>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank updated="yes">5</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <!-- B1 -->
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
</data>
```

---

**What I expect**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

def parse_commented_nodes(root):
    """
    Returns something like
    {
        "A1" : "./country[@name='Liechtenstein']/neighbor[@name='Austria']",
        "B1" : "./country[@nmae='Singapore']/gdppc"
    }
    """
    return {}

tree = et.parse("ex.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
res = parse_commented_nodes(root)
```

---

**My idea**

1. Read the file as a text.
2. Find the lines which comes before a comment.
3. Get parents iteratively from the nodes up to the root.

But I have a problem 'getting parents' from the above method. For example,

```
annotated_node = root.find(".//neighbor[@name='Austria']")
print(annotated_node.find("..")) # None
print(annotated_node.find("./..")) # None
```

I have searched ways to get parents (or get full XPATH) of a node using the default `xml` module of Python but couldn't find an effective one.

---

[How to read commented text from XML file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59543824/how-to-read-commented-text-from-xml-file-in-python)

My question is similar with the above but not a duplicate. It finds 'comments' but I need 'nodes before comments.'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read commented text from XML file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59543824/how-to-read-commented-text-from-xml-file-in-python)

Comment: The OP wants to do more than just get the comment nodes.

Comment: With lxml, comment nodes are easily found (using `.xpath('//comment()')`) and so are preceding siblings (using `.getprevious()`). The parent of a node is obtained with `.getparent()`. Doing these things with ElementTree is not impossible, but certainly more challenging.

Comment: why do you want to know the xpath of the comments?

Comment: @mzjn That is perfect to me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @balderman I need the xpath of the nodes which come before comments not comments themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by using ***lxml*** as [**@mzjn**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/407651/mzjn) suggested.

```
from lxml import etree as et

def parse_commented_nodes(tree):
    res = {}
    for node in tree.iter():
        if "function Comment" in str(node.tag):
            res[node.text] = tree.getpath(node.getprevious())
    return res

tree = et.parse("ex.xml")
res = parse_commented_nodes(tree)
```