# How to keep comments in existing XML while adding any new comment

Tags: python, xml, comments, lxml, elementtree

XML1 is:

```
<Price>
    <Amount>100</Amount>
    <Amount>102</Amount>
    <Amount>103</Amount>
</Price>
```

I want to search these many amount in XML2 without changing its format

XML2 is:

```
<List>
    <Item>
        <SN>1</SN>
    <!--street no1-->
        <Local>
            <Area>1</Area>
        </Local>
        <Price>
            <Amount>100</Amount>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Apple</Name>
            </Next_Item>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Orange</Name>
            </Next_Item>
        </Price>
        <Price>
            <Amount>200</Amount>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Apple</Name>
            </Next_Item>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Orange</Name>
            </Next_Item>
        </Price>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <SN>2</SN>
        <Price>
            <Amount>220</Amount>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Apple</Name>
            </Next_Item>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Orange</Name>
            </Next_Item>
        </Price>
        <Price>
            <Amount>300</Amount>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Apple</Name>
            </Next_Item>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Orange</Name>
            </Next_Item>
        </Price>
        <!--street no2-->
        <Local>
            <Area>2</Area>
        </Local>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <SN>3</SN>
        <Price>
            <Amount>102</Amount>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Apple</Name>
            </Next_Item>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Orange</Name>
            </Next_Item>
        </Price>
        <Price>
            <Amount>200</Amount>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Apple</Name>
            </Next_Item>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Orange</Name>
            </Next_Item>
        </Price>
        <!--street no3-->
        <Local>
            <Area>3</Area>
        </Local>
    </Item>
</List>
```

And if amount matches then I want to insert comment that too without removing its existing comments
Output.xml:

```
<List>
    <Item>
        <SN>1</SN>
    <!--street no1-->
        <Local>
            <Area>1</Area>
        </Local>
        <!--Marked-->
        <Price>
            <Amount>100</Amount>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Apple</Name>
            </Next_Item>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Orange</Name>
            </Next_Item>
        </Price>
        <Price>
            <Amount>200</Amount>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Apple</Name>
            </Next_Item>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Orange</Name>
            </Next_Item>
        </Price>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <SN>2</SN>
        <Price>
            <Amount>220</Amount>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Apple</Name>
            </Next_Item>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Orange</Name>
            </Next_Item>
        </Price>
        <Price>
            <Amount>300</Amount>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Apple</Name>
            </Next_Item>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Orange</Name>
            </Next_Item>
        </Price>
        <!--street no2-->
        <Local>
            <Area>2</Area>
        </Local>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <SN>3</SN>
        <!--Marked-->
        <Price>
            <Amount>102</Amount>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Apple</Name>
            </Next_Item>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Orange</Name>
            </Next_Item>
        </Price>
        <Price>
            <Amount>200</Amount>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Apple</Name>
            </Next_Item>
            <Next_Item>
                <Name>Orange</Name>
            </Next_Item>
        </Price>
        <!--street no3-->
        <Local>
            <Area>3</Area>
        </Local>
    </Item>
</List>
```

I have used `tc.insert(0, ET.Comment('Marked'))`which changes the format of final output.xml by removing all the comments
I have went through the questions in forum and referred to some of the codes present but couldn't get the desired output.xml

I tried with this

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root1 = ET.parse('C:/Python/xml1.xml')
root2 = ET.parse('C:/Python/xml2.xml')
amounts = set(e.text for e in root1.findall('.//Amount'))
for item in root2.findall('.//Item'):
    prices = item.findall('.//Price')
    for price in prices:
        amount = price.find('Amount').text
        if amount in amounts:
            item.insert(0, ET.Comment('Marked'))
ET.dump(root2)
```

Thank you for your time and help

Comment: Add you python code please. Questions should provide a [mcve].

Comment: Why not to use XSLT for the task?

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky
Not any problem with  XSLT but I am just not familiar with it

Comment: @LMC added one example which traverse through the XML2 but in output.xml all the comments removed

Comment: "changes the format of final output.xml by removing all the comments..." - lxml does not remove any comments. ElementTree on the other hand ignores comments by default (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59561426/407651).

Comment: @mzjn Thank you for the link I am able to print xml with comments now.
But somehow I am not able to add comment <!--Marked--> just above Price instead its printing above Item element

Comment: @mzjn 
I thought both are included in one question I posted....
Should I post another question about it..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248960/discussion-between-anonymous-and-mzjn).